# Confusion in understanding Gauss Divergence theorem and Stokes theorem

Tags: vector-fields, stokes-theorem, divergence-theorem

Gauss divergence theorem says from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem

that

$$
\iiint_{V}(\nabla\cdot F)\,dV=\iint_{S}(F\cdot n)\,dS.
$$

Now, let $G=\nabla\times F$ for a nice vector field $F$, then from the above result, we get
$$
\iint_{S}(G\cdot n)\,dS=\iiint_{V}(\nabla\cdot G)\,dV=0,
$$
since $\nabla\cdot G=\nabla\cdot (\nabla\times F)=0$. But, it seems it should not be true and I could not understand what I am missing. Indeed, Stokes theorem (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem#Theorem) does not give this value to be zero always.

Can someone please explain what is going on here?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Gauss' theorem is the *divergence* theorem and Stokes' theorem is the *curl theorem*. They are calculating different things. In Gauss the *normal* vector to the surface is taken and this surface encloses a volume. In Stokes a curve is the boundary of a surface and you are looking at surface integral versus line integral.

Comment: Thanks. Still, I could not get it properly. So, do you mean the above integral is non-zero?

Comment: This integral is zero because it applies Gauss to a vector field that has divergence zero.

Comment: Then it should be zero by Stokes theorem as well. But I could not come up with that. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: But Stoke's theorem exactly computes this integral which is zero by Gauss theoem. I am sure I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: Gauss has a *closed* surface $S$ which is the boundary of the volume $V$. Stokes has a *not closed* surface $S$ which has a boundary $\gamma$. It seems that this is confusing you.

Comment: Thanks. Ok, so if we take closed surface in Stoke's theorem, the surface integral of the curl of $F$ would be zero.